# Fuzzy Matching beetwen two list with different lenght

Tags: pandas, match, data-science, fuzzywuzzy

after doing web scraping for a project while merging two datasets I realized that some data were not matched because the strings are not exactly the same ( example: Usop = Usopp), so to overcome this problem I am using FuzzyWuzzy library, the problem is that the datasets to be merged have different sizes

```
list1 = df1['Name'].tolist()
list2 = df1['name'].tolist()
mat1 = []
mat2 = []
for i in list1:
    mat1.append(process.extract(i, list2, limit=2))
df1['matches'] = mat1
```

ERROR: Length of values (2416) does not match length of index (190)
the length problem cannot be solved, how could I solve it?